# How to show grouping in gridview from two SQL tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have two Tables One is Desktop And Other is Desktop Main

Desktop Table

```
create table Desktop (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    Company varchar(35), 
    Model_A varchar(50), 
    Model_B varchar(50), 
    Dealer varchar(35), 
    Invoice_Num varchar(50), 
    Purchase_Date varchar(15), 
    Warranty_Days int, 
    Warranty_Exp_Date varchar(15), 
    Warranty_Status varchar(20), 
    Machin_Type varchar(50), 
    System_Serial varchar(50), 
    Processor varchar(50), 
    Processor_Generation varchar(50), 
    Processor_speed varchar(30), 
    RAM varchar(30), 
    Hard_Disk varchar(30), 
    OS varchar(50), 
    OS_Bit varchar(15), 
    OS_Key varchar(40), 
    UserName varchar(50), 
    Location varchar(40), 
    System_IP varchar(30),
    MS_Office_Ver varchar(50), 
    MS_Office_Key varchar(50), 
    Quick_Heal_IP varchar(50), 
    Quick_Heal_Key varchar(50),
    Remarks varchar(100), 
    EntredBy varchar(30), 
    EntryDate varchar(15), 
    UpdatedBy varchar(30),
    UpdatedDate varchar(15)
)
```

DeksktopMain Table

```
create table DesktopMain (
    Service_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Desktop (ID),
    Request_Date varchar(15), 
    Call_loggedby varchar(20), 
    Service_No varchar(30), 
    Order_No varchar(30),
    Days_Pending int, 
    End_Date varchar(15), 
    Working_Status varchar(3), 
    Service_Centre varchar(30), 
    Engineer_Name varchar(40), 
    Mobile_No varchar(25), 
    KeyBoard_Old_FRU varchar(20), 
    KeyBoard_Old_Sir varchar(20), 
    KeyBoard_New_FRU varchar(20), 
    KeyBoard_New_Sir varchar(20), 
    Mouse_Old_FRU varchar(20), 
    Mouse_Old_Sir varchar(20), 
    Mouse_New_FRU varchar(20), 
    Mouse_New_Sir varchar(20), 
    Problem_Detail varchar(400), 
    Part_Installed varchar(50), 
    Part_Serial varchar(50), 
    Report_Detail varchar(200)
)
```

I have `Foreign key` ID in Desktop Main. i want to show 1 row from Desktop Table and related to that Desktop ID which match `foreign key` in Desktop Main Shows under that 1 row. Like Drill Down

Comment: ok and your question is?

Comment: Hope this post is helpful http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-GridView-Grouping-Group-similar-GridView-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx